# How can I parse this SOAP response

Tags: php, soap

I get SOAP response with PHP CURL as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope
    xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns1:GetRTResponse
            xmlns:ns1="http://advtest.forexpros.com/">
            <GetRTResponse xsi:type="xsd:ArrayOfString">
                <root>
                    <symbol id="53085" lastTimeStamp="1419026361">
                        <data symbol="53085" ask='11474.6' bid='11392.8' other='11433.7' date="12/19/2014 21:59:21.000" change='518.0' changep='4.75' tick="none" />
                    </symbol>
                </root>
            </GetRTResponse>
        </ns1:GetRTResponse>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

How can I parse `bid` attribute from data using PHP? Why `var_dump` returns `string(679)""` ?

Comment: What have you tried? Why did it not work? Please format your SOAP message. Currently it is difficult to read.

Comment: Try SimpleXml - http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php

Answer (score 0):

In PHP there are several ways, use SimpleXML or create a DOMDocument, try XPath or use a XSLT-Stylesheet or simple string match or preg match the file ... last 2 possibilities are the worst ...
i think "string(679)" says, that this xml is a string with a length of 679.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use native PHP class SoapClient to sned the request then receive an array or stdClass in response?
For example, you could use [PackageGenerator](https://github.com/WsdlToPhp/PackageGenerator) to create a PHP package that will ease you the way you send the request without having to handle the XML request as you'll have a PHP object